# ira_laser_tools merging not working

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following xacro code creating 3 hukoyu links on my robot model:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robot_name">

        <!-- Hokuyo Laser -->
        <link name="hokuyo_link_top">
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>

            <visual>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://rrbot_description/meshes/hokuyo.dae"/>
                </geometry>
            </visual>

            <inertial>
                <mass value="1e-5" />
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
            </inertial>
        </link>

        <joint name="laser_joint_top" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.0 0 0.29" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <parent link="chasis"/>
            <child link="hokuyo_link_top"/>
        </joint>
    <!-- </xacro:macro> -->

<!--  -->

    <xacro:macro name="laser_left">
        <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link_left">
            <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <visualize>false</visualize>
            <update_rate>20</update_rate>
            <ray>
                <scan>
                    <horizontal>
                        <samples>720</samples>
                        <resolution>1</resolution>
                        <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
                    </horizontal>
                </scan>
                <range>
                    <min>0.10</min>
                    <max>10.0</max>
                    <resolution>0.05</resolution>
                </range>
                <noise>
                    <type>gaussian</type>
                    <mean>0.0</mean>
                    <stddev>0.01</stddev>
                </noise>
            </ray>
            <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
                <topicName>/scan_left</topicName>
                <frameName>hokuyo_link_left</frameName>
            </plugin>
            </sensor>
        </gazebo>

        <!-- Hokuyo Laser -->
        <link name="hokuyo_link_left">
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>

            <visual>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://rrbot_description/meshes/hokuyo.dae"/>
                </geometry>
            </visual>

            <inertial>
                <mass value="1e-5" />
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
            </inertial>
        </link>

        <joint name="laser_joint_left" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.27 -0.20" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <parent link="chasis"/>
            <child link="hokuyo_link_left"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>

<!--  -->

    <xacro:macro name="laser_right">
        <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link_right">
            <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <visualize>false</visualize>
            <update_rate>20</update_rate>
            <ray>
                <scan>
                    <horizontal>
                        <samples>720</samples>
                        <resolution>1</resolution>
                        <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
                    </horizontal>
                </scan>
                <range>
                    <min>0.10</min>
                    <max>10.0</max>
                    <resolution>0.05</resolution>
                </range>
                <noise>
                    <type>gaussian</type>
                    <mean>0.0</mean>
                    <stddev>0.01</stddev>
                </noise>
            </ray>
            <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
                <topicName>/scan_right</topicName>
                <frameName>hokuyo_link_right</frameName>
            </plugin>
            </sensor>
        </gazebo>

        <!-- Hokuyo Laser -->
        <link name="hokuyo_link_right">
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>

            <visual>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://rrbot_description/meshes/hokuyo.dae"/>
                </geometry>
            </visual>

            <inertial>
                <mass value="1e-5" />
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
            </inertial>
        </link>

        <joint name="laser_joint_right" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.0 -0.27 -0.20" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <parent link="chasis"/>
            <child link="hokuyo_link_right"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>
    
</robot>
```

The topics from these two lasers are successfully echoing data but I need to merge them into the **/scan** topic to use in the gmapping process.

The following is my *ira_laser_tools* node definition in my launch file I'm using to attempt merging the data:

```
<node name='scan_merger' type='laserscan_multi_merger' pkg='ira_laser_tools' output='screen'>
        <param name="cloud_destination_topic" value="/test"/>
        <param name="scan_destination_topic" value="/scan"/>
        <param name="destination_frame" value="/hokuyo_link_top"/>
        <param name="laserscan_topics" value="/scan_left  /scan_right"/>
</node>
```

With all that done, my */scan* and */test* topics are completely empty.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing. I  would appreciate some help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373973/ira_laser_tools-merging-not-working/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-15**:
I'm not sure you can merge the scans into a different plane.  Your two side lidars are at `z = -0.2`, but `hokuyo_link_top` is at `z = 0.29`.  For the sake of experimenting, what happens if you change the destination frame to one of the side lidars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue was that the **scan_merger** node needed to be delayed long ennough for gazebo to initiate.
I got the hint from [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/225183/ira_laser_tools-merger-doesnt-subscribe-to-topics-from-laser-in-gazebo/?answer=229186#post-id-229186).

I don't know if a deplay factor can be added to a node in a launch file. So instead of using a single launch file, I'm using two.

I moved the `<node ..... >` code above into a separate launch file and launch that after the first one which contains the gazebo node i:e `<include file='$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch'/>`.

That way, gazebo is up and running, I launch my launch file containing the **scan_merger** node, the **/scan** and **/test** topics now echo merged data from my hokuyo scan topics.

---

Originally posted by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) with karma: 247 on 2021-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0